# Display form on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a index page and wish to display a form from a different controller that I created on the index page. I have 3 folders in my view. In the folder called index, I have a html file called index and in the folder called job I have form.html and show.html.

[image]

so in my index.html I have

```
<h1>Complete Job Applications</h1>
<%= render 'job/form'%>
```

When I run the code I receive this error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. I think I know why but am not too sure. Instead of displaying the form so the user can fill out all the needed text fields so it can be submitted it's submitting it right away (just a guess though). Does anyone have any ideas to how I can display a form from another controller on my index page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to initialize the object that is passed to the form, for example, lets say your view looks like this:

```
# job/form
<%= form_for(some_model_instance, method: :get) do |form|
...
<% end %>
```

To render that form from another controller's action, make sure to initialize `some_model_instance` before rendering the partial, so:

```
# controller which has the index action
def index
  @some_model_instance = SomeModel.where(id: 1).first
end

# index.html.erb
<h1>Complete Job Applications</h1>
<%= render partial: 'job/form', locals: { some_model_instance: @some_model_instance } %>
```

Comment: In the index method that you have I replaced SomeModel with the name of the model class that the form is from. And all this is happening in my main_controller correct not my job_controller. But what is some_model_instance: you have before @some_model_instance

Comment: it gives me this error Missing partial main/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

Comment: Could you show me the form_for line that's in your job.html.erb partial?

Which controller has the index action?